# How can I deep clean grout in my kitchen?

Tags: tile, grout

I've tried homemade recipes with baking soda and lemon juice. I've also tried store bought cleaner/repair stuff. So far, it's still dingy.

Anyone know of a powerful (and somewhat safe) product that can get the grout back to what it use to be so I can reseal it?

Comment: might be easier to scrape them out and just regrout.

Comment: If you haven't tried a grout saw, get one: they're only $8 at Home Depot. Then try scraping as little of the old grout out as possible. You should only have to scrape out about 1/32" to get down to clean grout. And don't try to do it all at once. Just take your time and enjoy your handiwork.

Comment: I've had good success using a steam cleaner for cleaning grout. Prior to that, the only thing I'd found to work well was lots of bleach and scrubbing.

Answer (score -2):

Mild Sulfamic acid (I've bought it at Home Depot years ago) and wear gloves.

Comment: Could you expand this a bit? Maybe include how to apply it, how to work with it, and what safety precautions need to be taken.